# how to use innerHTML when the string is an Iframe tag in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, iframe

There is a string type variable, which contains an iframe tag. I need angular to identify the string as an iframe HTML tag and populate the HTML.

Currently, angular is constructing its has string.

Please check the below code

**Variable:**

`this.longDesc  = "<iframe width="something" height="something" src="something" ></iframe>"`

**html file**

`<div class="description-panel" [innerHTML]="longDesc" ></div>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Step1 : Import the below part in ts file

```
import {DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

Step 2 :Define constructor in perticular ts file

```
constructor(private domSanitizer:DomSanitizer) {}
```

Step 3:-Use below code in ts file according to requirement (method/ function or constructor)

```
this._EmittersService.longDescemitted$.subscribe(obj => {
      this.longDesc = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(obj or any html content);
or 
this.longDesc = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml('<iframe width="something" height="something" src="something" ></iframe>')
     });
```

Comment: works, thanks. but I dont belive we need to import "SafeHtml, SafeStyle, SafeScript, SafeUrl, SafeResourceUrl" is required to be imported.