# Angular 5 unable to show iFrame

Tags: angular, angular5

I want to show data content which may contain text, image and iFrame (youtube etc) in Angular 5, like below:

```
<p><iframe frameborder="0" height="460" scrolling="no" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/uDGwCO1HDg0" width="300"></iframe></p>
<p><img class="ui-widget-content" src="http://localhost/stmd/public/uploads/media/original/1540875164_i4.jpg" /></p>
<p>How we work</p>
```

I have done the below code in .html:

```
<div class="content" [innerHTML]="first.content"></div>
```

The above is displaying the content along with the text and image but iFrame is missing.

Later, I found the post [Angular 4 | iframe to be populated in innerHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46172057/angular-4-iframe-to-be-populated-in-innerhtml) and did exactly what they said in the .ts file, see below:

```
import {DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';

constructor(
        private contentService:ContentService,
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private _global: AppGlobals,
        private meta: Meta, 
        private title: Title,
        private domSanitizer:DomSanitizer
        ) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.first = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(data.data.first);
}
```

*The data.data.first is containing the images, text and iframe.*

But I see the entire content is missing (no text, no image, no iframe).

How Can I display the iFrame along with the images and text? Any Help?

Answer (score 0):

Use this `<div class="content" [innerHTML]="first"></div>` . Replace `first.content` with `first` only.

I believe `data.data.first` is something like this `<iframe width="something" height="something" src="something" ></iframe>`.

Comment: it says `[object object]`. I have used `first.content | safe: 'html'` and it works. Anyway, thanks for your answer.